# Add Watermark to Word Document using Word Interop C#

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, cpu-word, watermark

I want to add a watermark to all the pages of a word document using only the Word Interop library of c#.
What i want to achieve is the same thing that you will get using the "Add Watermark" functionality of word 2016/2019 [image: like this]

i've found similar questions but all of them add the watermark only to the Headers/Footers of the document.
Is there any way to achieve this without using external libraries?

Comment: "What i want to achieve is the same thing that you will get using the "Add Watermark" functionality of word 2016/2019 ... i've found similar questions but all of them add the watermark only to the Headers/Footers of the document" -- err, that's how "Add Watermark" works.

Comment: yes, but i can't find how to print the text shape over all the pages using c#

Comment: You add it to the headers, just like Add Watermark does.

Comment: any answer  for this question ?